# Outlook Addin: Iterating over items of a fodler doesn't return all items

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a folder with 800+ items. When seen via Outlook, I can see only ~40 items, with the message "*There are more items in this folder on the server*" appearing at the bottom of the items list.

When I try to iterate over all the items of the folder via code in my Add-in, I'm only getting the ~40 visible items. I've tried the following methods with no success:

- foreach on folder.Items
- GetFirst()/GetNext() on folder.Items
- GetLast()/GetPrevious() on folder.Items
- while !table.EndOfTable on folder.GetTable()
- Redemption ExecSQL
- Redemption MAPITable

All of these methods provide me the needed information, but only for the mentioned 40 items, instead of the full 800 items.

Does anyone have a solution/recommendation on how to iterate over the *full* list of items/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to connect in the online mode (turn caching off) or make sure Outlook downloads all items in the folder - make sure "Mail to keep offline" slider is all the way to the right (All) in the Exchange service properties dialog.

Comment: Is there a way to "connect in online mode" via an addin? (I've already found the slider, but that would force users to download all items locally)

Comment: No, not while the profile is already being used. But you can reopen a particular folder in the online mode using Extended MAPI or Redemption - use the MAPI_NO_CACHE (0x200) flag. In Redemption, call RDOSession.GetFolderFromID and pass, for example, MAPI_NO_CACHE (0x200) +  MAPI_BEST_ACCESS (0x10).

Comment: Using Redemption to reopen the folder in NO_CACHE mode solved the problem. Thanks!